# QVector + QScopedPointer - Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function

Tags: qt, vector, smart-pointer

Есть метод, который при вызове создает большой массив `QVector<uchar>`   (SIZE:  354792000), память под который выделяется/освобождается динамически (в runtime), для удобства использую QScopedPointer. Выглядит следующим образом:

```
void someMethod(int SIZE) {
  chVec.reset(new QVector<uchar>(SIZE));
       /*циклы заполнения массива*/
  chVec.data()->clear();
  chVec.data()->squeeze();
}
```

Создавая массивы небольшого размера - никаких проблем, также можно создать один массив большого размера, но при повторном вызове получаю ошибку "Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function". Прошёлся дебагером, ошибка возникает при попытке выделить место под новый массив :

```
template <typename T>
QVector<T>::QVector(int asize, const T &t)
{
    Q_ASSERT_X(asize >= 0, "QVector::QVector", "Size must be greater than or equal to 0.");
    if (asize > 0) {
        d = Data::allocate(asize);
        Q_CHECK_PTR(d); /*<------ Выбрасывает ошибку*/
        d->size = asize;
        T* i = d->end();
        while (i != d->begin())
            new (--i) T(t);
    } else {
        d = Data::sharedNull();
    }
}
```

Вот так выглядит `Data::allocate(asize);` :

```
Q_REQUIRED_RESULT static QTypedArrayData *allocate(size_t capacity,
            AllocationOptions options = Default)
    {
        Q_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(QTypedArrayData) == sizeof(QArrayData));
        return static_cast<QTypedArrayData *>(QArrayData::allocate(sizeof(T),
                    Q_ALIGNOF(AlignmentDummy), capacity, options));
    }
```

Что это может быть? Утечка памяти (невозможно выделить такой большой кусок непрерывной памяти повторно, так как при предыдущем вызове память не освободилась?) ?... Никак не могу понять, в чём же проблема, перед выходом из области видимости метода даже специально руками чищу массив и освобождаю память... Буду признателен за любой совет

Comment: а какая у вас ОС и её разрядность?

Comment: собираю на Win 7, x64

Comment: может у вас программа 32-битная и 2 гигабайта заканчиваются? Распределение памяти для QVector происходит с помощью malloc() в файле `corelib\tools\qarraydata.cpp` в функции 
    `QArrayData *QArrayData::allocate`, может просто с malloc/free поэкспериментировать ...

Comment: Спасибо Вам за предложение, попробую.. Но всё же не ясно, почему это происходит, ведь первый раз память под массив (SIZE: 354792000) выделяется без каких-либо проблем, затем процедура очистки должна была бы освободить её...

Comment: может фрагментация кучи какая-то хитрая происходит, ведь во время обработки сообщений Qt постоянно занимает/освобождает множество мелких порций памяти

Comment: Павел, спасибо Вам большое! Вы были правы, проблема решилась сменой комплекта с mingw32 на mingw64. Судя по монитору ресурсов, когда массив был проинициализирован - программа заняла 620 мБ оперативной памяти, после освобождения вернулась к исходным 200 мБ (рисую большие изображения), всё же странно, за 2 ГБ я так и ны вышел, однако BadAlloc всё же поймал. Если оформите свой комментарий в виде ответа - отмечу его как решение!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась сменой комплекта с mingw32 на mingw64. Дело во фрагментации памяти, при необходимости выделения больших непрерывных областей (для хранения односвязного списка, как в моем случае) следует собирать проект при помощи mingw64 (если позволяет разрядность ОС), либо использовать флаги large-address-aware (для 32-разрядных ОС)